# npm request moudule not giving the output

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-request

Why when I run the npm request module the output I get is `undefined`?

```
const request = require('request');
request({
  url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1301%20lombard%20street%20philadelphia',
  json: true
  }, (error, response, body) => {
     console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your code should work properly if request is installed. The possible reason why you get undefined is a problem with your internet connection.

Start with checking if you can access Internet at all. You can try this code:

```
 require('dns').resolve('www.google.com', function(err) { 
   if (err) { 
     console.log("No connection"); 
   } else { 
     console.log("Connected"); 
     } 
 });
```

Comment: I have installed request.What might be the problem with internet connection?

Comment: You just don't have internet connection from your app. Maybe it's blocked by the firewall. Your code works well on my machine, but I also receive 'undefined' if I switch off WiFi.

Comment: Then what am i supposed to do??

Comment: I would start with checking if that's the reason. You can try it with this code and see if your app is able to connect with the Internet:

`require('dns').resolve('www.google.com', function(err) {
  if (err) {
     console.log("No connection");
  } else {
     console.log("Connected");
  }
});`
Unfortunately, there's plenty of reasons why you can't access internet.

Comment: The output is 'connected'.

Comment: And what you receive if you console log everything? error and response?
As I said, your code works fine on my machine.

Comment: This is something I get                                                                                 error: { Error: connect EINVAL 0.0.0.12:8080 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at internalConnect (net.js:971:16)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.emitLookup [as callback] (net.js:1106:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:97:10)
  code: 'EINVAL',
  errno: 'EINVAL',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '0.0.0.12',
  port: 8080 }
statusCode: undefined
body: undefined

Answer (score 0):

I checked for proxy using
 env|grep -i proxy
and then unset proxy for http_proxy or other proxies which is set.The command for that is:unset http_proxy